# bind a combo-box to a List with "static" content and show content from database on WPF with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

i am having a combo box and i want to show when you click on it the Gender "Female" or "Male" , the same time i want to read from my database which "Gender" has the selected Employee. So, generally i want to read and show on my combo-box the "sex" from my database but when you click on it i want also to show the two different options that you will have ("Female" or "Male"). The problem is now that i know how to bind to a combo-box so i can show the content on it from an Observable collection, but i do not know first how i can bind a property on it and how i can show also the same time the two different choices that some one can choose.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey throwingexceptions. First at all Wellcome to StackOverflow. Could you please post [what you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so we can better see whats your exact problem.

Comment: What I do is get a collection from the DB and then insert my own created objects into that collection.  Like an object called "ALL" with an id of 0 that I can use for the top level selection of the combo box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your **ObservableCollection** binding. It sounds as if that's working fine and it is responsible for providing all the options you want exposed in the dropdown of the ComboBox.

It sounds like you want to then show by default the **Sex** property that was obtained from your database.

Presumably, you will have some **Sex** property on your DataContext that is implementing **INotifyPropertyChanged**

```
private string _sex;

public string Sex
{
    get { return _sex; }
    set
    {
        if (_sex != value)
        {
            _sex = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("Sex");
        }
    }
}

private void WhateverMethodYouHaveGettingDataFromDB()
{
    //... do whatever it needs ...

    Sex = // get sex from database...
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Now you have a bindable property that represents the **Sex** that you obtained from your database.

To push this onto the default exposed value in your ComboBox, simply bind it to the **SelectedValue** property.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding --your observable collection--}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Sex}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris first of all for your answer, sorry that it took it so long to answer you and also to thank you for answer, it helped me to archive my target, i did something else and worked but you inspired my, so thanks a lot.